# Representations of an integer as the sum of other integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integer-partitions

Given a finite set $S$ of (distinct) integers $s_1, \dots, s_n$ and an integer $x$, I'm looking for all representations (where order is important)
$$
x=\sum_{i=1}^ks_{t_i} (t_i\in\{1,\dots,n\})
$$

#### For example

1. $x = 4, S = \{1,2\}$: Five solutions.
   $$4=1+1+1+1=1+1+2=1+2+1=2+1+1=2+2$$
2. $x = 7, S = \{3,5\}$: No solution.
3. $x$ odd, all $s_i$ even: No solution.

<sub>This is for a photo gallery on a website and can easily be solved programmatically using recursion. However, it left me thinking about the theory, which may or may not help optimize the algorithm.</sub>

Now, as a generalization of 3., it can be easily seen that there are no solutions when $$\gcd(s_1, \dots, s_n)\ne \gcd(x, s_1, \dots, s_n)$$

What other conclusions can we draw, particularly on the existence of solutions?

Is this problem known by a specific name? (Edit: yes, I'm looking for *[restricted partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Restricted_partitions)*; related: [Coin problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem), [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem))

Comment: So the summands may occur more than once in the sum, but always have coefficient $1$, right? You could simplify the representation by $x = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i s_i$ with some nonnegative integers $a_i$. This question can be restated as asking for a description of the elements in the additive submonoid $〈S〉$ of $ℕ_0$.

Comment: By this you get $x ∈ 〈S〉 ⊂ (S) = (\gcd(S))$, where $S$ is the ideal in $ℤ$ generated by $S$, so $x$ has to be a multiple of $\gcd (S)$ as well, which is already what you observed.

Comment: Oh, I’m sorry. I just realised that you want to distuingish represantations of the same summands with different orders. I think, you probably should first tackle the problem to infer whether $x ∈ 〈S〉$ at all by looking at the elements of $S$

Comment: You could start by looking here: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29).

Comment: @CarlNajafi Thank you, I knew there was some simple term for this. So `Restricted partitions` is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @K.Stm. I guess finding the number of permutations is not really hard. Actually, I'm mainly interested in criteria for (non-)existence of solutions. For example: $1\in S\implies$ trivial solution exists; $x>1 \wedge \{2,3\}\subset S\implies$ solutions exist; $x<min(S)\implies$ no solutions...

Answer (score 1):

The problem of deciding whether there is a solution for $x$ and $S$ is difficult to characterize in general, but I do know a useful result in the special case where $|S| = 2$.

**Theorem.**  If $S = \{m,n\}$ where $m,n$ relatively prime, then there is a solution for $x$ if and only if there is *not* a solution for $mn - m - n - x$.

Note that this easily generalizes to when $m,n$ are not relatively prime, because if $(m,n) = d > 1$, you can just consider $\frac{x}{d}$ and $S = \{\frac{m}{d},\frac{n}{d}\}$.

**Proof.**
Note that there is a solution for an integer $y$ if and only if we can write $y$ as a sum of $m$s and $n$s, i.e. $y = am + bn$, where $a,b \ge 0$.

First, suppose towards contradiction that there is a solution for *both* $x$ and $mn - m - n - x$.
Then adding the two solutions together gives a solution for $mn - m - n$.
Thus we can write $mn - m - n = am + bn$.
But this implies $a \equiv -1 \pmod n$ and $b \equiv -1 \mod m$,
so $a \ge n-1$ and $b \ge m - 1$, so
$$
mn - m - n = am + bn \ge (n-1)m + (m-1)n = 2mn - m - n,
$$
a contradiction.

Therefore, it suffices to show that there is a solution for at least one of $x$ and $mn - m - n - x$.
By the fact that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, we can find $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$
am + bn = x
$$
Let $a \equiv a' \pmod n$ and $b \equiv b' \pmod m$, where $0 \le a' < n$ and $0 \le b' < m$.  Then
$$
a'm + b'n \equiv x \pmod {mn}
$$
Let $a'm + b'n = x + kmn$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
If $k \le 0$ we are done because $x = a'm + b'n + (-k)mn$ is a sum of $m$s and $n$s.
Conversely, if $k > 0$, we write
\begin{align*}
mn - m - n - x
&= mn - m - n - a'm - b'n + kmn \\
&= (n - 1 - a')m + (m - 1 - b')n + (k-1)mn
\end{align*}
and since $n -1 - a', m - a - b', k-1 \ge 0$, there is a solution for $mn - m - n - x$.

$$
* \quad * \quad *
$$

A [well-known corollary](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Chicken_McNugget_Theorem) to this theorem is that there is always a solution for $x$ whenever $x > mn - m - n$, but not when $x = mn - m - n$.

$$
* \quad * \quad *
$$

**EDIT:** The above theorem only applies when $m$ and $n$ are nonnegative.

- If exactly one of $m$ and $n$ is negative, then clearly there is a solution for *any* $x$ since there is a solution for $1$ and $-1$.
  I.e., write $am + bn = 1$ and $cm + dn = -1$ for $a,b,c,d \ge 0$, and then we have
  $(a|x|)m + (b|x|)n = |x|$ and $(c|x|)m + (d|x|)n = -|x|$.  (This suffices since $x$ is equal to either $|x|$ or -|x|).
- If both $m$ and $n$ are negative, then the situation is basically the same as when they are positive.  In this case, there is a solution for $x$ if and only if there is a solution for $-x$ using $S = \{|m|,|n|\}$.

Comment: First, your theorem applies to *natural numbers* $m,n$ only, where the question was about *integers* (I accidentally mixed that up, but then decided to leave it like that). Counterexample: $S=\{-2,3\},x=-7=5*(-2)+3$
Second, I really don't understand your argument "consider it modulo m and modulo n". That leaves us with $a+1\equiv 0\pmod n, b+1\equiv 0\pmod m$. Now what? Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 If $a \equiv -1 \pmod n$ and $b \equiv -1 \pmod m$, then $a \ge n-1$ and $b \ge m-1$, which implies $mn - m - n = am + bn \ge 2mn - m - n$, contradiction.  I'll add this into the answer, as well as a note at the end about $m,n$ negative.